# SSL problem "SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG" for Raspbian Stretch?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, apache-httpd, raspbian-stretch

I have a problem connecting to my https, but not my http.

This is the error I receive "SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG". I also tried

```
Listen 443 https
```

from other suggestions.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is the version I have of Raspbian:
Raspbian Stretch Lite
Minimal image based on Debian Stretch
Version: November 2017
Release date: 2017-11-29
Kernel version: 4.9

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ netstat -tln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

It looks like my raspbian is only listening on IPV6.
I turn off the redirect and the website will load with http(port 80) just fine.

```
# Redirect / https://www.website.com/
```

etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName website.com
ServerAlias www.website.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

Redirect / https://www.website.com/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.website.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =website.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/ssl

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/09_01_2017/ca-bundle-client.crt
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/09_01_2017/website.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/private/private.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName website.com
ServerAlias www.website.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

Redirect / https://www.website.com/

</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
Listen 80
Listen 443
```

Comment: SSL errors are caused by HTTPS, as HTTPS uses SSL to secure traffic.

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was use these 2 commands:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
```

Then everything worked!  I hope this helps someone else!